# type error when excuting ajax code in django

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, django

I am using jquery ajax to get json data into my webpage (Django framework).  I can not seem to render the json data (my first step is simply to do a console.log(data)-not working). I am getting a type "unknown" so I think that may be part or all of the problem.  In my simple template, I have a button that makes an ajax call which is not working.  Code below includes my urls.py file, views.py file with the relevant function, and the ajax code on my website.  The network tab on the firefox developers page says code 200, I am assuming this means that my urls.py and views.py were correct, but please let me know if this is true.  My app is on pythonanywhere.  I am using console.log to if the ajax call can bring up the json data. It did not. My javascript triggers the error code--not sure whey. Thank you for any help you may provide.

urls.py(see last url):

```
app_name = 'beach'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),  #when you go to the beach directory, it looks at this urls.py file, this says go to views.py in this folder, index function
    url(r'^(?P<lakes>[a].*)/$', views.searched, name='lakes'),  #regex = starts with a letter then it can be anything
    url(r'^(?P<gnisid>[0-9]+)/$', views.gnis, name='GNIS'),  #regex = numbers ony, many.  name-'GNIS' a link to the HTTPResponseRedirect or directly from the template from a link
    url(r'^(?P<tmap>tmap)/$', views.tmap, name='tmap'),
    url(r'^(?P<profile>profile)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^(?P<ajax>profiles/default)/$', views.defaultajax, name='ajaxgnis')   
]
```

views.py

```
def defaultajax(request, ajaxgnis):
    x = {"foo": "bar"}
    jsondata = json.dumps(x)
    return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

template with the javascript code (lots of testing, sorry)

```
window.onload = function () {

    $('#putprofile').click(makeProfile);

    function makeProfile(){
        $.ajax({
                url: "/beach/profile/default/",
                dataType: "json",

                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');

                    $('#result').html('<p>status code: '+jqXHR.status+'</p><p>errorThrown: ' + errorThrown + '</p><p>jqXHR.responseText:</p><div>'+jqXHR.responseText + '</div>');
                    console.log('jqXHR:');
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('textStatus:');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log('errorThrown:');
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                    console.log('datatype:');
                    console.log(typeof data);
                },

                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert('Load was performed. Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information! ');
                    console.log('jqXHR:');
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    console.log('textStatus:');
                    console.log(textStatus);
                    console.log('data:');
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });

    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question where the error that you mention is coming from. Is it in the success function? What do you mean "console.log(data)" is not working? Is it what's raising the error? Is it just not logging anything?

Comment: Thank you for responding. When I click the button and the makeProfile function is run, the error alert is triggered rather than the success alert.  If there was success, the function should then log the data (seen in the views.py) to the console.  The data are not logged to the console.

Comment: Also, in the error, I am logging the datatype, which comes up as "unknown." I think this should be json.

Comment: Can you see from the firefox network tab the content of the response body? You say the response returns a 200 OK, so the body itself may give some clues.

Comment: Will.  I don't think so.  Here is my website url: http://www.beachtemp.us/beach/profile/.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem:

(1) I had an existing url named profile, and my original ajax call was /profile/default, I think this caused some problems with the urls in the urls.py.  I changed the ajax call url in my template to `/beach/profiles/default`, beach is my app name.  Final url in my urls.py file was: `url(r'^(?P<defaultajax>profiles/default)/$', views.defaultajax, name='ajaxgnis'). Note again that the "/" in`/beach/proiles/default` was critical since without the "/" the url would start at the root "beach" directory.

(2) I had an error in my named group  not matching the variable in my views.

(3) I caused myself confusion by not "reloading" the app in the web tab of pythonanywhere.